# Using EF with database first on a remote and secured database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, postgresql

I am wondering if it's possible to use Entity Framework to scan a database and build an EDMX model in the following scenario:

(It's actually a PostgreSQL database and I'll probably use [dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/), but I assume the principle is the same, and I'm asking a similar question on the devart forums.)

The database is secured with SSL *and* the administrator has provisioned access for a single IP address - the address of the machine that hosts my ASP.NET website.

Will it be theoretically possible to set up Visual Studio (on my dev machine) and the host machine in such a way that I'll be able to access this database with my dev machine? What will I need to set up on the host machine to allow it to be used as a proxy (I have full admin access to it)?

Without having tried anything, it seems like the only option is to install Visual Studio on the host machine, build the EDMX model there, and import it into my dev environment and create the actual database locally, but I only want to do this as a last resort.

Comment: Can't you just ask the administrator to export the database schema with pg_dump --schema_only and give the script to you so that you can recreate it locally? Installing vs there sounds like trying to kill a sparrow with cannon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yeah I'll ask. The data is overly protected and the admin is overly anal about security, so I might have to use a cannon.

Comment: @user982119 You can install (or simply copy) postgres tools to server and use `pg_dump --schema_only` to dump the schema of the DB into a simple sql script.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, I must add that I'll only have read-only access to the database. Will that schema dump command still work?

Comment: @user982119 Yes, it will. `pg_dump` does not alter a DB so it only need RO access.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy postgres tools and libraries to server machine (or install full postgres DB on it) and use `pg_dump` to dump DB schema and/or data to a file.

Read [`this page`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) for the details about `pg_dump`.

If you want schema only dump use `--schema_only` key for `pg_dump`.

Answer (score 1):

[dotConnect for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) allows you to connect through a proxy. You can install a proxy server on a computer, which hosts your ASP.NET website and has access to the PostgreSQL database. You can connect to a database via this proxy server. For this you need to apply the following connection settings:

```
PgSqlConnection conn = new PgSqlConnection("host=<DATABASE HOST>;port=5434;uid=<USER ID>;pwd=<PASSWORD>");
conn.ProxyOptions.Host = "PROXY HOST";
conn.ProxyOptions.Port = 3128;
conn.ProxyOptions.User = "PROXY USER ID";
conn.ProxyOptions.Password = "PROXY PASSWORD";
```

[dotConnect for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) also can connect via SSL. For this you need to configure your server so that it supports SSL connections and apply the following connection settings:

```
conn.SslOptions.CACert = "D:\\Certificates Pg\\client\\root.crt";
conn.SslOptions.Cert = "D:\\Certificates Pg\\client\\client.crt";
conn.SslOptions.Key = "D:\\Certificates Pg\\client\\client.key";
conn.SslOptions.SslMode = SslMode.Require;
```

[dotConnect for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) allows creating SSL connection via proxy.